# What can I change in my routine to get to 20 push-ups?

Tags: push-ups, parkour

This is what I've been doing:

Each serie has the maximum number of repetitions I can do. So, the first serie is 10 reps then the next serie is 7 and so on, until I cannot lift my weight.

Each repetition is done at a moderate speed and without any delay between reps.

After each serie I rest for at least 15 mins (not sure if it's too much) so that the effect of the lactic acid should be gone by them (not sure if that is true either).

I don't use weights, and I'm a skinny guy (about 155 lb. or 70 Kg)

Lastly I rest for two days before repeating the same routine.

Comment: You say you are skinny. You are 155 lbs... but how tall are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resting too long. To train for muscular endurance, i.e. to do 20 pushups in a row, shorter rest intervals are better. Try resting for 30 seconds between sets rather than 15 minutes.

And you don't need two days between body weight exercises. Every other day is a good frequency when you're starting.

Answer (score 0):

Rest time should be shortened significantly. Rest only around a minute and like J.Vance said, train every other day, it's a great way to build the muscles endurance. Even if you can't keep your same amount of push-ups, you would just go for failure, every set. If you go for failure every set you will be able to see those 20 push-ups in no time!