# How to get to 20 pull-ups while having also muscle growth?

Tags: pull-ups, parkour

As a followup to [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/34079/25596), can I get to 20 pull-ups (instead of push-ups), doing the same routine as in the ascepted answer? i.e. going for failure, with moderate speed repetitions, and resting half a minute between each serie.

Also, is it possible to get some muscle growth while doing that routine? I'm asking because I don't know if one can train to have muscular endurance while having muscular growth at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20 pullups is more strength than endurance. The only way to get you to 20 pullups, is to increase strength in the relevant muscle groups.

So in short, you don't need to worry about the dichotomy of "strength OR endurance" here. I'd save those thoughts for when you start thinking of doing some number that requires you to go on for several minutes.

Comment: I see, should I still be going for failure but with longer resting periodos between series to gain strength? Is it even possible to gain strength without using weights but just the pull-up exercises?

Comment: Oh yeah, your bodyweight is more than enough, at least for now. Though you should look into doing some variations, rather than just a normal pullup every single time. The body responds to variety. As for the rest periods, keep it short. For each set, do as many PROPER reps as you can, then save energy for the next set. 1-2 minutes rest tops.